# What is the minimal lines of text needed for a desktop entry to autostart after GUI login?

Tags: debian, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, productivity, autostart

Most desktop Linux distros allow you to autostart applications in a flexible manner as described in [Freedesktop.org's Autostart spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html). There are two steps: 1. `mkdir -p $HOME/.config/autostart` 2. create a *.desktop file with some lines of text.

None of the guides I have found explain what are the minimum lines needed for your *.desktop file.

What is the minimal lines of text needed for a desktop entry to autostart after GUI login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By experimentation[1], here is the minimal number of lines I found to be necessary 4 lines.

Example - firefox.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=firefox %u
Type=Application
Name=firefox.desktop
```

The line with `Name=` seems unnecessary[2] (`nautilus` lets you start the application fine without this line) but experimentation shows `Name=` to be necessary o/w it won't autostart after GUI login.

---

[1]
I couldn't find any good text on what is required[2] and what is optional lines I decided to try experimentally. I started with an [autogenerated *.desktop file which was about 100+ lines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login). Then I pared it down to just four lines.

[2]
Apparently the Freedesktop.org "autostart" spec is utilizing another spec called ["Desktop Entry" spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) which should answer the question directly (instead of experimentally). Unfortunately the spec says there are only TWO required keys: "Name", "Type". This explains why the "Name" line was needed in my experimentation. But no application will start... so you need a third line if you want to start an application (in this example I use "Exec").